# Iterative imputation in R

Tags: r, iteration, regression, subset, imputation

My R version is 4.1.2. I was trying to do iterative imputation using linear regression( i.e. regressing each covariate on all other covariates repeatedly until the values converge). At the zeroth iteration, I use the mean of each column. Unfortunately, after the iteration, I am having this error message

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = Ximpute[, j] ~ Ximpute[, -j], drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :
> invalid type (list) for variable 'Ximpute[, -j]'

By the way, `Ximpute` is of class dataframe. I don't know why `Ximpute[,-j]` seems problematic.

```
X <- df[,1:4]
M = is.na(X)

Ximpute  = X

for(j in 1:ncol(X)){
  Ximpute[M[,j],j] = mean(X[,j],na.rm=TRUE)
}

maxIters  = 20
threshold = .05
converged = FALSE
nIters    = 0
while(!converged){
  nIters = nIters + 1
  Ximpute_old = Ximpute
  for(j in 1:ncol(X)){
    fitX_j = lm(Ximpute[,j]~Ximpute[,-j])
    Ximpute[M[,j],j] = fitX_j$fitted[M[,j]]
  }
  print(max(abs(Ximpute_old - Ximpute)/abs(Ximpute_old)))
  if( max(abs(Ximpute_old - Ximpute)/abs(Ximpute_old)) < threshold){
    converged = TRUE
  }
}
```

My professor used these same codes last year and it worked, so I am wondering if there is a revision of these codes or I am probably missing something.

Comment: You haven't shown us your `df` dataframe, but I'd guess that at some point you're selecting one row or one column, and the subsetting code returns a vector instead of a dataframe.  To prevent this, every time you do subsetting use `drop = FALSE`, e.g `X <- df[,1:4, drop = FALSE]`.

Comment: How many columns do you have and has this always been more than 2? `lm(Ximpute[,j]~Ximpute[,-j])` works on a table with 2 columns, where you basically compare first with second(excluding first). This means if you have a df with 3 columns you  have 2 columns in -j. I think in case you have more columns in df, you should use something like `lm(Ximpute[, j] ~ ., data = Ximpute[, -j])`

Comment: Please do show us the result of `dput(df)`, so we can answer your question instead of making these guesses.  If it's too big, then put together a smaller example that has the same error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.